# Проблема с переносом

Tags: modx

При переносе сайта возникла ошибка:

> Error 503 Site Temporarily Unavailable

Поправил config.inc.php в корне, manager, controllers, core/config, импортировал базу данных на сервер (utf8mb4 -> utf8). Примечательно, что если в корне сайта в config.inc.php оставить путь к папке core как на локальном (по умолчанию — /core/), то сайт нормально отображается (всё, кроме каталога товаров на главной, который я вывожу собственным сниппетом).
Проверял core/config/config.inc.php — написано всё правильно, database_user, database_password проверил — подключается. В $database_dsn прописал unix_socket. Все пути в файле проверил — пути modx указаны правильно.

Скачал в корень сайта test_config.php. Он выдал:

> $database_dsn is not set correctly

Нашёл тот же, что и у меня, вопрос, но не нашёл для себя ответа: http://modx.pro/help/2306/

ЧЯДНТ?

Comment: открыть логи апача, он вам там сам напишет ЧЗНТ !

Comment: *$database_dsn is not set correctly* — поиск выдаёт такую [тему](http://forums.modx.com/thread/85481/503-site-unavailable-error-migration-of-site-between-servers). указывать в этой переменной рекомендуемое содержимое не пробовали?